# How to not generate random ID with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

*My code :*

```
this.collectionRef=this.db.list('user-list/'+userKey+'/collection/bouteille');

this.collectionRef.push(item);
```

*Database :*

```
collection >
 Bouteille>
 --L5O2298mWHtsacZJkgl: "item"
```

My key (`--L5O2298mWHtsacZJkgl`) is generated, but i would like to set myself the key in the database. How can i do that ?

Comment: use set() instead of push()

Comment: For more info just check out [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write)